# Crawling website returns bad data

Tags: web-crawler, rapidminer

I am using rapid miner to crawl website from specific data. The problem is if I try to crawl website frequently it supplies bad data.

If I see the same data from other IP address it shows different data comparing to the one I crawled on different IP address.

Is there any solution to overcome this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with 'bad data' and 'different data comparing to [...]'? I do not know what your problem is. Please provide a process and a exact description of what goes wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Many websites today, especially websites worth mining(ie: linked) use sophisticated methods for detecting and discouraging crawling for all but the few large search engines they have agreements with.

Try varying the browser code you send as well as distributing the crawling among a group of machines rather than a single machine.  Running a bunch of micro instances on AWS is preferable to one large instance.  Also make sure you set a delay in between requests as that's both considerate, and will help disguise your crawler.